# Updating the quantity if field exists, Inserting a new entry if not mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called

**usercodes**, id is on auto increment

```
  id|user|code|quantity
```

currently i am inserting new fields like this.

```
  $query= "INSERT INTO usercodes (user,code,quantity) values 
  ('".$user."',(SELECT code FROM promocodes WHERE id = '".$id."'), 
   '".$quantity."' )";
```

Lets say there is an existing entry of.

```
       id|user|code|quantity
        1|john|code1|1
```

How do i update the quantity instead of inserting another row if a user named **john** already has an existing code of code1?

Expected result

```
        id|user|code|quantity
        1|john|code1|2
```

**Instead of**

```
        id|user|code|quantity
        1|john|code1|1
        2|john|code1|1
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's simple what you need is to check if data is already present in table so first try the select query.

I assume that the user and the code is something unique for all users so:

**Step 1:** Run the select query with user and code value and check if there is any data with same details in table.

**Step 2 a:** Check the number of rows if it's 1 then you have the data, Here get the quantity for that row add/subtract the quantity value from it and then run UPDATE query.

**Step 2 b:** Check the number of rows if it's 0 then you have no data, Here run INSERT query.

```php
 $Query = "SELECT * FROM usercodes WHERE user = ? AND code = ? LIMIT 1";

  $user = "USERVALUE";
  $code = "CODEVALUE";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $code);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           //Here get the quantity and add the amount u want to add in it and run the update query
        }
    }else{
          //Store data as new record 

    }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I have a small question again. Lets say i have points field in a table user, and points field in the code table. How do i select and compare these two fields and run another query if the user.points field is greater or equal than points.code field?

Comment: What's the identifier? is there any unique id or unique username in both tables?

Comment: Yes select from user points where email=email and select points from code where id = id.  i want to compare those two points to see if the user has enough points to purchase the code

Comment: `SELECT points AS pointsInUserTable, (SELECT points FROM code WHERE code.id = 1) AS pointsInCodeTable FROM users WHERE email = 'abc@mail.com'` try that query it will get the points from both table and than You can compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
  $query= "INSERT INTO usercodes (user,code,quantity) values 
  ('".$user."',(SELECT code FROM promocodes WHERE id = '".$id."'), 
  '".$quantity."' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + 1";
```

Make sure that you have a KEY for the column 'user' and make the user column [UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)